# How to run stackblitz project

Tags: angular, stackblitz

Sorry for the stupid question.

Beginner with angular (and stackblitz) I created a stackblitz project to ask for help on an angular subject (reactive forms)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4vdtbe?file=src%2Fselect%2Fselect.component.ts,src%2Fselect%2Fselect.component.html
But I can't run it.
How can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there are many issues, i've just fixed some of them

1. First, look at the stackblitz console, it helps you to look for issues
   [image: Console]
2. index.html should have main.ts component(which has selector ), that's why you need add  in index.html

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app></my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

3. main.ts template has default code. Add a selector of your component. Import your SelectComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SelectComponent } from './select/select.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, SelectComponent],
  template: `
    <app-select></app-select>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

4. select.component.ts, make your component as standalone and import nessesary modules

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
} from '@angular/forms';

export interface IDocument {
  id: string;
  label: string;
  maxQuantity: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.css'],
})
....
```

5. Fix other issues, with your code
   Here, a demo, there I cut some code(with issues) just to launch the application
   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wiskwl?file=src/select/select.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's a very complete answer, I've fixed the last problems